# Trying to generate random background color within document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, codepen

I am trying to set the background of my web app to a random color every time it loads and every time a *"New Quote"* button is pressed. The function I use to generate the random background color is `random_bg_color()`.

I have called it within the `$(document).ready(function(){})`. I am creating this web app using codepen.io. The link to my web app is [here](https://codepen.io/nicktsan/full/odEXPv/). Currently, the page only loads "white" as the background color. Any feedback on how to fix this is appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" />
        <title>CodePen - Random Quote Getter</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'>

        <style>
          #new-quote-btn {

          }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body translate="no" >
        <div class='container-fluid'>
          <button id='new-quote-btn'>New Quote</button>
        </div>

        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome-iconpicker/3.0.0/js/fontawesome-iconpicker.js'></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            random_bg_color();
            document.getElementById("#new-quote-btn").addEventListener("click", random_bg_color);
          });

          function random_bg_color() {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
            console.log(bgColor);
            document.body.style.background = bgColor;
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This looks like a homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the background color randomly with the Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725872/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-randomly-with-the-javascript)

Comment: Where did you add jQuery CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery CDN in your `<head>` tag. See line 10 below. I can see it is working in your codepen after adding jQuery.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" />
    <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" />
    <title>CodePen - Random Quote Getter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      #new-quote-btn {

      }
   </style>
</head>
```

And in your javascript update your code like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    random_bg_color();
    $("#new-quote-btn").on("click", function() {
        random_bg_color();
    });
});

function random_bg_color() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
    console.log(bgColor);
  document.body.style.background = bgColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to web development so this helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem @nicktsan :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a link to JQuery as mentioned and your getElementById has an incorrect selector so no event listener is getting added. Remove the # and it will work -

```
document.getElementById("new-quote-btn").addEventListener("click", random_bg_color);
```

Since you are using JQuery you can use this code to attach an event listener -

```
$("#new-quote-btn").on("click", function() {
    random_bg_color();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to web development so this helped me a lot!